# akka can I override the stop functionality?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Is it possible to capture the stop event on a actor whether is be from PoisonPill or context.stop()? Essentially, I would like to have the actor become() a "dieing" event loop, so that I can wait for things to close, and then when things do close, call context.stop(self) that will close normally. This seems kind've cyclical, so I am open to different approaches.

I should also ask, is there a way to to override the way the parent closes it's children?

Sorry that there are two questions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple answer to both questions: define your own message type for initiating your shutdown sequence and handle that within your actor in any way you like.

Comment: Roland, Thank you for the reply. I have defined my own "KillPill" message, however this seems to become a problem when a actor a couple of layers up the hierarchy shutdowns down. In this case, the actor that would normally send the KillPill message, just does a context.stop on its children.  I would like to be able to define that a parent send the KillPill instead of the default functionality, so that the children can do their shutdown sequence. Thank you for the time.

Comment: If an actor is forcibly shut down, then there is nothing more its descendants can do: it is an abort operation. Orderly shutdown needs to be done from the top down.